# Why is my cron job not running at minute 0 and 30

Tags: cron

I have a cron job set up, and I have a problem with the frequency.

Here's what my crontab looks like:

`0,10,20,30,40,50 * * * * /home/script.sh`

I also tried the short version

`*/10 * * * * /home/script.py`

The script writes in a CSV, and I can see that it writes only at minutes 10,20,40 and 50.
It seems like it is not running at 00 and 30. Any ideas?

Comment: You can try changing your cron just a bit to something like this: 0,10,20,30,40,50 * * * * /home/script.sh; echo \`date\` >> /tmp/scripts.log. If you see that a date is written at 0th and 30th minute of the hour in /tmp/scripts.log, you know that the cron is running. You can then evaluate /home/script.sh or /home/script.pyp to figure out why it's not writing data to your file.

Comment: Thanks, good idea. And it seems like you're right. My script.log has the entries. I'll check my main script again.